# Parse error <br /> error

Tags: php, html, css

I have a problem with my PHP & HTML code.

I enter a PHP block in my HTML code. I enter a `<br />` HTML tag and I get an error.

Here is my code:

```php
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <?php

        $A = 50;
        $B = 10;
        $and = $A + $B;
        $dif = $A - $B;

        echo($and);
        <br />                     
        echo($dif);

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

I get the following error:

```
Parse error: parse error in - on line 15
```

Comment: You can't drop html into your php like that.  Should be `echo "<br />";`

Comment: `echo $and . '<br />' . $dif;`

Comment: Everyone is being a little harsh to this. Clearly someone trying to learn the language with a little misunderstanding and down voting a valid question, a pretty decent attempt with all the right details. How about trying to help some?

Comment: Also, @user3426513, you haven't really used a [`function`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php), but you can read about them there. For others, don't start saying `echo` is a function, because 'it is a language construct'.

Answer (score 2):

Close and reopen your php tags:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

  <?php
        $A = 50;
        $B = 10;
        $and = $A + $B;
        $dif = $A - $B;

        echo($and);
  ?>

  <br /> <!-- Outside of PHP execution -->                    

  <?php
       echo($dif);
  ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `<br />` is a html tag. 
You need to echo it out to have it work as you expect.

```
echo($and);
echo "<br />";                     
echo($dif);
```

Comment: This is also a valid option. There is much debate about `echo`ing HTML, but it is something you should know. especially, when you start mixing PHP and HTML a lot more.

Comment: Example: `echo "<p>{$A} + {$B} = {$and}</p>";`, place that after `echo($dif);` and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

It's saying that on line 15 there is an error. Line 15 appears to be `<br />`. This is html, not valid PHP. When php goes to read your code, it doesn't know what to do with it. You should exit PHP to write the HTML, than start up php again.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

  <body>

<?php
  $A = 50;
  $B = 10;
  $and = $A + $B;
  $dif = $A - $B;

  echo($and);
?>

<br />  

<?php                   
  echo($dif);
?>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place your code like below. You can output with single line code as well.

```
  <html>
     <head>
       <title></title> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php
         $A = 50; $B = 10;
         $and = $A + $B; 
         $dif = $A - $B; 
        echo ($and)."<br />".($dif); ?> 
   </body> 
</html>
```